# How can I separate the pixels in an image and put them into a C# array?

Tags: c#, image, pixel

I want to import photos and examine each pixel to determine its RGB value and 
then put each pixel (or its equivalent value in RGB) in an array or similar data structure that keeps the pixels in their original order.

The most important thing I need to know is how to separate the pixels and determine each pixel value.

Answer (score 2):

```
        Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"C:\...");

        Color[,] pixels = new Color[img.Width, img.Height];

        for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++)
            {
                pixels[x, y] = img.GetPixel(x, y);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A fast version of the upvoted answer:

```
    public static int[][] ImageToArray(Bitmap bmp) {
        int height = bmp.Height;   // Slow properties, read them once
        int width = bmp.Width;
        var arr = new int[height][];
        var data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), 
                   System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, 
                   System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        try {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
                arr[y] = new int[width];
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(
                    (IntPtr)((long)data.Scan0 + (height-1-y) * data.Stride),
                    arr[y], 0, width);
            }
        }
        finally {
            bmp.UnlockBits(data);
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Use Color.FromArgb() to map the pixel value to a Color.